# How to convert a date in hive with no leading zeroes

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

I have a string column, which has value like '5/1/21' , '5/14/21' which is of format day/month/year , but the column values doesn't have leading zero's  like '05/01/21' , '05/14/21'

I have tried

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('5/15/21','MM/DD/YY'),'DD-MM-YYYY')
from  dev_irloi_wrk.Final_Ryder_data
```

but its giving the values like '2021-12-27'
am unable to understand from where 12 and 27 are coming and how to get to the format '2021-05-14' , '2021-05-01'

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: `5/14/21` is not day/month/year.

Comment: Try using `'M/d/y'`.

Comment: i mean  not 'day' 'month' , 'year' but 5 represent day 14 month and 21 year

Comment: @GordonLinoff  thank you its working , but what was the logic of 'M/d/y', can i kindly know

Comment: @Chandu . . . It follows the rules for patters that Hive uses.  I don't know where you got your formats from, but the Hive formats (really Java) are well documented.

Answer (score 1):

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('5/15/21','mm/dd/yy'),'mm/dd/YYYY');
+-------------+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+
| 05/15/2021  |
+-------------+
1 row selected (0.397 seconds)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you this time).

Answer (score 0):

Hive uses SimpleDateFormat.
Date and time patterns are documented here: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Use `M/dd/yy` or `M/d/yy`, case is important.

`y` or `yy` - year parsing logic:

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"),
> SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some
> century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before
> and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.
> For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat
> instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be
> interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be
> interpreted as May 4, 1964.